# Averaging R objects

Tags: r, object, lapply

Lets say that I have several R objects, e.g. `lm` outputs:

```
m1 <- lm(x ~ y, data = data, subset = sample==1)
m2 <- lm(x ~ y, data = data, subset = sample==2)
m3 <- lm(x ~ y, data = data, subset = sample==3)
m4 <- lm(x ~ y, data = data, subset = sample==4)
```

and now I want to average those objects, i.e. I want to average all estimates produced by `lm`. I would be very happy If I could get summary statistics of all the parameters in the objects, i.e. average intercept etc. What simplifies the problem is that all the objects would be roughly the same, just calculated on different samples.

Is there any way to do this in a general fashion, that is, using a single general function rather that taking all the individual values and averaging them one at a time? Also, I would need this kind of function for different kinds of objects.

Probably `lapply` could be used in some way, however how to deal with multiple (varying) layers of nesting?

Comment: Just don't do this. You shouldn't average the coefficients and you should *definitly* not average p-values, R² or AIC. Instead you could fit a model without stratifying the data.

Comment: @Roland - I understand, this is just an simplified example so I don't need into too much unimportant details. I am *not* interested in obtaining average p-values trust me. But you're right - I'll edit my Q to make it clear. And what I am dealing with are plausible values - so I *have* to average things like intercepts (http://www.ierinstitute.org/fileadmin/Documents/IERI_Monograph/IERI_Monograph_Volume_02_Chapter_01.pdf).

Comment: The package `broom` contains functions to convert things like the output of `lm` into data frames which can then much more easily be manipulated.

Comment: @BryanHanson - `broom` is marvelous! This is what I needed. I didn't know this one before.

Comment: I think it is new, and definitely, should have been invented long ago.  Have fun.

Comment: @Tim It tidy up the `lm` object (if I am not mistaken).  But, how is it helping to your original question ie. `averaging out`?.  I understand that it has `tidy`, `glance` to get the results in the better format, though.

Comment: @akrun - averaging is not that hard, the problem for me to extract multiple values from the objects in simple way. `broom` seems fine for that, however now I see that is is not perfect.

Comment: @Tim What I meant is about Roland's comment to not average it.  Also, my solution did gave you all the components that you wanted in the data.frame format.

Comment: `lst <- lapply(split(data, data$Sample), function(.data) {
                  lm1 <- lm(x~y, data=.data)
       cbind(summary(lm1)$coef, R.square=summary(lm1)$r.squared, AIC=AIC(lm1))})`

Answer (score 0):

This should work (example using the mtcars dataset):

```
library(dplyr)
meanpars <- mtcars %>%
              group_by(cyl) %>%
              do(mod = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)) %>%
              summarise(
               intercepts = coef(mod)[1],
               wtbeta     = coef(mod)[2]) %>%
              summarise(
               meaninter = mean(intercepts),
               meanbeta = mean(wtbeta))
```

Here's with your toy data plugged in:

```
library(dplyr)
meanpars <- data %>%
              group_by(sample) %>%
              do(mod = lm(x ~ y, data = .)) %>%
              summarise(
               intercepts = coef(mod)[1],
               ybeta     = coef(mod)[2]) %>%
              summarise(
               meaninter = mean(intercepts),
               meanbeta = mean(ybeta))
```

Edit: If you don't want to average the coefficients in the end, just remove the last summarise function and you'll still get a data.frame with the results from your models.